# Linux-MSBuild-project not starting in VisualStudio

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a basic MSBuild project in c++ for Linux. I was able to compile and debug it without any problems until I re-installed Debian on the server. I have since installed `g++`, `GCC`, `gdb`, `gdbserver`, `make`, `rsync`, and `zip`.

Visual-Studio compiles the project remotely without any problems, but when it tries to start it, I get [the following prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfKoe.png).

I tried using different versions of Visual-Studio, like prev2022 and 2019, and installing Linux on a completely different machine in my network.

Here is the content of the `.vcxproj` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x86">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x86">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{63047eae-971e-48d1-b78a-91ea7faeda86}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Linux</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>xy</RootNamespace>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>15.0</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <ApplicationType>Linux</ApplicationType>
    <ApplicationTypeRevision>1.0</ApplicationTypeRevision>
    <TargetLinuxPlatform>Generic</TargetLinuxPlatform>
    <LinuxProjectType>{D51BCBC9-82E9-4017-911E-C93873C4EA2B}</LinuxProjectType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM'" Label="Configuration">
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM'" Label="Configuration">
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'" Label="Configuration">
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'" Label="Configuration">
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <UseOfStl>libstdc++_shared</UseOfStl>
    <RemoteRootDir>~/debug</RemoteRootDir>
    <PlatformToolset>Remote_GCC_1_0</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM64'" Label="Configuration">
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM64'" Label="Configuration">
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings" />
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared" />
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <RemoteCopySourceMethod>rsync</RemoteCopySourceMethod>
    <RemoteCCompileToolExe>g++</RemoteCCompileToolExe>
    <RemoteCppCompileToolExe>g++</RemoteCppCompileToolExe>
    <ValidateArchitecture>true</ValidateArchitecture>
    <MultiProcNumber>4</MultiProcNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="AuthorizationManager.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="Cookie.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="CreateDirectoryModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="DeleteDirectoryModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="Directory.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="FileHelper.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="FileSystemManager.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="FileUploadManager.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="FinishModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="HttpRequest.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="HttpRequestCreator.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="HttpResponse.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="HttpServer.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="LoginModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="LogoffModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="main.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="MoveDirectoryModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="NavModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="ParentModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="PathHelper.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="PauseModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="RefreshModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="RenameDirectoryModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="ResumeModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="SocketListener.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="StartModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="StopModule.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="StringCompairer.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="StringConverter.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="Timer.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="UserManager.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="AuthorizationManager.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="byte.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="byteSection.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Cookie.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="CreateDirectoryModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="DeleteDirectoryModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Directory.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="FileHelper.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="FileInfo.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="FileSystemManager.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="FileUploadManager.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="FinishModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="HttpMethod.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="HttpModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="HttpRequest.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="HttpRequestCreator.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="HttpRequestHandler.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="HttpResponse.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="HttpServer.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="LoginModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="loginResult.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="LogoffModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="MoveDirectoryModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="NavModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="ParentModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="PathHelper.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="PauseModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="RefreshModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="RenameDirectoryModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="RequestHandler.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="ResumeModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="serverSettings.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="SocketListener.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="SortedVectorHelper.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="StartModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="StopModule.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="StringCompairer.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="StringConverter.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="Timer.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="uid.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="UploadFile.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="User.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="UserCredentials.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="UserManager.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Link>
      <OptimizeforMemory>false</OptimizeforMemory>
      <AdditionalOptions>-pthread %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </Link>
    <ClCompile>
      <CppLanguageStandard>c++17</CppLanguageStandard>
      <CLanguageStandard>c11</CLanguageStandard>
      <AdditionalOptions>
      </AdditionalOptions>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>
      </PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <PostBuildEvent>
      <Message>xy</Message>
    </PostBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Link>
      <AdditionalOptions>-pthread %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </Link>
    <ClCompile>
      <UnrollLoops>true</UnrollLoops>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets" />
</Project>
```

...and of the `.vcxproj.user` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <DebuggerFlavor>LinuxDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
    <RemoteDebuggerWorkingDirectory>{the-path}</RemoteDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
    <RemoteDebuggingTarget>{my-ip}(username={my-user-name}, port=22, authentication=None)</RemoteDebuggingTarget>
    <RemoteGDBPath>
    </RemoteGDBPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Have you changed some configurations or maybe some configurations were affected by the re-installation? You may need to check the configurations of the connection and focus on the debugging part. If you followed some guides to set before, please check the guides again.

Comment: The configuration of the project is exactly the same. Or which one do you mean? And I followed the same steps to set up the server and Visual-Studio like the last time, where it worked.